# How to call python from Php?

Tags: python, php

I've created this live messaging web app with PHP and another web app (SMS Spam Detection) using machine learning. I want to add the spam detection feature in live messaging app. But I don't know how. Plus these two applications are running on different localhost.
I just want to include that web page of spam detection app on my live messaging application.

Comment: Now they are from two different servers (Am I correct ?) , so please create an endpoint at the python side so that the PHP side can call it thru sending say the relevant message so that it can return the spam score (usually 5 means spam)

Comment: If they're on different servers, then it may be feasible to create a "microservice" (tiny HTTP server with an API) for the Python application (eg by using the Flask framework, see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/), and call it from the PHP script.